# Unknown keyword in installer: Ubuntu 11.04 boot from USB

Tags: 11.04, installation, usb-creator

I've just downloaded Ubuntu 11.04 (Haven't we all?) and created a bootable USB with my existing 10.04LTS installation. However, when I try to boot it it gives me a message similar to: Unknown keyword in installer. and leaves me at a boot:_ promt (which does not do anything)

Any solutions will be incredibly helpful, because I want to use new Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are experiencing the same bug as in [can't install with usb pen drive, SYSLINUX problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34088/cant-install-with-usb-pen-drive-syslinux-problem/34089#34089).

Comment: Thanks for the super-quick reply; editing the syslinux.cfg file works.