# Ubuntu not loading from USB flash on HP netbook

Tags: installation, boot, usb, ubuntu-netbook, syslinux

Trying to install Ubuntu on a HP Netbook Mini 210-4150NR( 1GB RAM)

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS using uNetbootin and USB installer on USB. Changed the boot sequence in BIOS to load from the USB and it is recognising the USB.

On starting it shows the following message and is stuck at a blinking underscore:

**SYSLINUX 4.03 2010-10-22 EDD Copyright (C) 1994-2010 H. Peter Anvin et al**

based on various threads in this forum I tried formatting the USB flash drive as NTFS and installing and restarting but the BIOS did not recognise the same & went ahead to load windows.

I tried downloading a fresh iso using the link from the USB installer app, but the same result.

I tried the solution given at but to no avail  - [Wont boot from USB, stops at SYSLINUX copyright](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71655/wont-boot-from-usb-stops-at-syslinux-copyright)

Please help with installing ubuntu on my netbook. ( I am using a PNY 8GB USB flash)

Comment: What no one has any expert comments ???!!! no solution guys out there!!!

Comment: There are a number of reasons why this might happen. There are now a number of answers here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/71655/wont-boot-from-usb-stops-at-syslinux-copyright